# Make error for latex processing

Tags: make, latex, makefile

I want to execute the following Makefile:

```
main.pdf: main.tex main.bib
pdflatex main.tex
bibtex main.aux
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

It comes from this site: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Why_won.27t_LaTeX_generate_any_output.3F.

I type the command "make" in the same directory and get the following error message:

> make: *** No rule to make target `main.bib', needed by`main.pdf'. 
>   Stop.

I don't know how to procede. [This site](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) with error messages does not help me.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent starting from pdflatex because they are the rules to make the target. Hint from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739434/whats-wrong-with-this-makefile

Answer (score 1):

A working `Makefile` will be:

```
main.pdf: main.tex main.bib
    pdflatex main.tex
    bibtex main.aux
    pdflatex main.tex
    pdflatex main.tex
```

note that you can't simply copy and paste the thing, because the first character in the command line *MUST be a physical "TAB" character* (ascii code 8). How to enter it, it depends on your editor. `vim` should automatically switch to a mode protecting TABs when editing a makefile, but other editors I do not know.

Makefile syntax is, eh, funny.

I heartily suggest using something like [`latexmk`](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) (in standard repos) to do the job; it will take care of dependencies and of multiple passes quite nicely.